# React and Nodejs, admin configuration need a support

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, mongoose

Need to login and navigate from admin to dashboard, am getting successful but not logging in.

In app.js I have public & private route

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LockOutlined';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Link from '@mui/material/Link';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { loginAdminSuccess, loginAdminFailure, setAuthLoading } from '../../store/reducers/adminSlice.js';
import { adminLogin } from '../../Api/adminApi.js';


function Copyright(props) {

    return (
        <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary" align="center" {...props}>
            {'Copyright © '}
            <Link color="inherit" href="https://webappstudioz.com/">
                webappstudioz
            </Link>{' '}
            {new Date().getFullYear()}
            {'.'}
        </Typography>
    );
}
const Admin = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const defaultTheme = createTheme();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const isLoading = useSelector((state) => state.admin.isLoading);

    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    const handleLogin = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const userData = {
            username,
            password,
        };
        try {
            dispatch(setAuthLoading()); // Dispatch loading state
            const config = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
            }
            const response = await adminLogin(userData, config);

            if (response?.token) {
                console.log('Authentication successful Navigating to /dashboard');
                dispatch(loginAdminSuccess(response.token))
                console.log("Navigatye");
                navigate('/dashboard:token');
            } else {
                console.log('Invalid credentials');
                // setError(response.message || 'Invalid credentials. Please try again.');
                dispatch(loginAdminFailure(response))
            }
        } catch (error) {
            // Log the specific error that occurred
            console.error('An unexpected error occurred during login:', error);
            // Handle specific error conditions if needed
            dispatch(loginAdminFailure());
            setError('An error occurred. Please try again later.');
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Box>
                <ThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
                    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
                        <CssBaseline />
                        <Box
                            sx={{
                                marginTop: 8,
                                display: 'flex',
                                flexDirection: 'column',
                                alignItems: 'center',
                            }}
                        >
                            <Avatar sx={{ m: 1, bgcolor: 'secondary.main' }}>
                                <LockOutlinedIcon />
                            </Avatar>
                            <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                                Administrator Login
                            </Typography>
                            <Box component="form" noValidate onSubmit={handleLogin} sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
                                <TextField
                                    margin="normal"
                                    required
                                    fullWidth
                                    value={username}
                                    onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                                    id="username"
                                    label="User Name"
                                    name="username"
                                    autoComplete="username"
                                    autoFocus
                                />
                                <TextField
                                    margin="normal"
                                    required
                                    fullWidth
                                    value={password}
                                    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                                    name="password"
                                    label="Password"
                                    type="password"
                                    id="password"
                                    autoComplete="current-password"
                                />

                                {error && (
                                    <Typography variant="body2" color="error" align="center" sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
                                        {error}
                                    </Typography>
                                )}
                                <Button
                                    type="submit"
                                    fullWidth
                                    variant="contained"
                                    sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}
                                    disabled={isLoading}
                                >
                                    {isLoading ? 'Logging in...' : 'Login'}
                                </Button>
                            </Box>
                        </Box>
                        <Copyright sx={{ mt: 8, mb: 4 }} />
                    </Container>
                </ThemeProvider>
            </Box>
        </div>
    )
}


export default Admin;
```

Private route

Need a solution in the above for successful authentication we should navigate to dashboard else return to admin
for this in I have made private route which check the authentication.

Comment: if (response?.token) {
                localStorage.setItem('authToken', response.token);
                console.log('Authentication successful Navigating to /dashboard');
                dispatch(loginAdminSuccess(response))
                console.log("Navigate");
                navigate('/dashboard');
            } 
this will solve the status of login to dashboard